# Cant count up numbers < 1 while estimating the volume of a sphere using the Monte Carlo method in Python

Tags: python, montecarlo

For an assignment, I need to write a program that can estimate the volume of an n-dimensional sphere using the Monte-Carlo method. I think I'm very close to having it done, but there is one problem.

I feel like everything works fine, except the part where I need to count the number of `sum_x`s that are <1. It simply doesn't seem to add all of them together. How can I make it count all the `sum_x`s that are <1?

What can I do to fix this problem and make it count up all `sum_x`s < 1?

```
import random

def vol_sphere(n,s): #n is amount of dimensions, and s is the amount of points taken

    #grabbing random points
    for j in range(s):
        sum_x = 0
        count = 0
        for i in range(n):
            i = random.randrange(0,101)/100 #this might seem weird but I'm doing it so I can get decimals   
            x = i**2
            sum_x += x
        print("The sum of the x^2's is:", sum_x)
        if sum_x <= 1:
            count += 1
    v = count/s
    volume = (2**n)*v
    print(volume)
    
vol_sphere(3,1000000)
```

Comment: Your string is screwed up (you closed with a single quote in "x^2's".) Use double quotes instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting `count` to zero every iteration through the loop. Move the line `count = 0` before the loop.

Also, why not use `random.uniform(-1,1)` to generate coordinates uniformly between -1 and 1? Your current method is only generating positive coordinates, but the `2**n` in your volume calculation implies you are thinking of the cube each of whose sides goes from -1 to 1.

Comment: upvoted for the main answer. But you got the [-1,1], ```2**n``` part wrong. Having negative intergers to compute their square is useless, and changes nothing to probabilities. So the [0,1] interval and the ```2**n``` of the code is perfectly correct, and gives the correct value. That being said, the current code restrict the random values to a rough {0,0.01, 0.02, ...} subset that creates a non negligible error. So random.uniform(0,1) is better that this randrange/100 thing. (random.uniform(-1,1) is exactly the same here)

Comment: Note that since we need values between 0 and 1, ``random.random()`` is enough. And 60% faster than uniform.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's equivalent. There are two values in [-1,1] that map to every positive value in in (0,1], but only one value that maps to zero. So the probability of getting zero would change.  And why would you not just uniformly pick coordinates in [-1, 1] like you want to? It's literally just as simple and you don't have to worry about whether your "shortcut" screwed anything up.

Comment: Well, that's a view. But a mathematician (which I am, full disclosure) would tell you that measure of that single 0 is null. You don't measure the probability of a specific value. But that could be debattable. I too, when I use Monte-Carlo, I often abstain thinking, to avoid over-thinking (If I am trying to be too smart when coding a Monte-Carlo simulation, I often end up introducing a bias, when one interest of that kind of simulation is to reveal the bias we could have). So, I take your point. But that was not your initial point :-)

Comment: Note that using the same argument, one could tell you that you are the one introducing a similar problem. uniform(-1,1) can be -1 be never +1. So, you half the probability of being on the edge. But same answer: it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can easily check that on billions of run, you'll never get any -1, nor +1 nor 0 anyway.

Comment: So, from probability theory point of view, and more specifically, from measure theory point of view, no, really no, that is not a valid point. And "random.uniform" is almost twice expansive in terms of computation time (quite understadably: it is just ``random.random()*2-1``. So, same thing, plus 2 operations)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nick's answer (you reset count in the loop, when you should reset it just once; and you should use random.ramdom() to get a float uniform value from [0,1), instead of that random.randrange(0,101)/100 which introduce a rough discretization, and cost CPU — Nick's said random.uniform(-1,1), which is exactly the same here, since we don't really care for the sign, but cost 60% to 100% more CPU than random.random),  you should also consider relying on numpy batch computation, to avoid using for loop yourself.

```py
import random
import sys
import numpy as np

def vol_sphere(n,s): #n is amount of dimensions and s is amount of points taken

    #grabbing random points
    count = 0
    for j in range(s):
        sum_x = 0
        for i in range(n):
            # I renamed your random variable ii, because I'm not very
            # comfortable with reusing the iteration variable. Even tho 
            # you can do it, as long as you don't really need i's value
            ii = random.random() #this might seem weird but I'm doing it so I can get decimals   
            x = ii**2
            sum_x += x
# Commented print (those printing cost all the CPU)
#        print("The sum of the x^2's is:", sum_x)
        if sum_x <= 1:
            count += 1
    v = count/s
    volume = (2**n)*v
    print(volume)

def vol_sphere2(n,s):
    # Same, but does computation by batches of 10000 (acceptable tradeoff
    # between CPU and memory)
    count=0
    reals=0
    for j in range(0, s, 10000):
        X2=np.random.random((10000, n))**2 # Generate 10000×n random number, squared at once
        # X2.sum(axis=1) is the column of 10000 sums of n columns of X2
        # X2.sum(axis=1)<=1 is a column of 10000 True/False saying which are<=1
        # (X2.sum(axis=1)<=1).sum() is the number of True
        count += (X2.sum(axis=1)<=1).sum()
        reals+=10000 # if s is not a factor of 10000, then we will do slightly more than s points.
    print(count/reals*2**n)

vol_sphere2(n,s)
```

On my computer version 2 is 20 times faster than version 1.

Edit: just for fun, I add a one-liner answer

```py
((np.random.random((s,n))**2).sum(axis=1)<=1).sum()/s*2**n
```

Which use some memory, but not much code lines.

For example, an estimation of pi is

```py
((np.random.random((100000,2))**2).sum(axis=1)<=1).sum()/100000*2**2
```